# AVPlayer seektotime with Pangesturerecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use seektotime with Pangesture recognizer.But its not seeking as expected.

```
let totalTime = self.avPlayer.currentItem!.duration
    print("time: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime))")
    self.avPlayer.pause()
    let touchDelta = swipeGesture.translationInView(self.view).x / CGFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime))
    let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer.currentItem?.currentTime())!) + Float64(touchDelta)
    print(currentTime)
    if currentTime >= 0 && currentTime <= CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime) {
        let newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(currentTime, Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        print(newTime)
        self.avPlayer.seekToTime(newTime)
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong in here ?

Comment: if you use UISlider in moving seekToTime?

Comment: I'm not using UISlider to moving seektotime I'm just trying to backward and forward video with pangesture left and right moves

Comment: Use my sliderAction: in your Pangesture Actions, its hope helpful

Answer (score 0):

Think about what's happening in this line here:

```
let touchDelta = swipeGesture.translationInView(self.view).x / CGFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime))
```

You're dividing pixels (the translation in just the x-axis) by time.  This really isn't a "delta" or absolute difference.  It's a ratio of sorts.  But it's not a ratio that has any meaning.  Then you're getting your new `currentTime` by just added this ratio to the previous `currentTime`, so you're adding pixels per seconds to pixels, which doesn't give a logical or useful number.

What we need to do is take the x-axis translation from the gesture and apply a **scale** (which is a ratio) to it in order to get a useful number of seconds to advance/rewind the `AVPlayer`.  The x-axis translation is in pixels so we'll need a scale that describes seconds per pixels and multiple the two in order to get our number of seconds.  The proper scale is the ratio between the total number of seconds in the video and the total number of pixels that the user can move through in the gesture.  Multiplying pixels times (seconds divided by pixels) gives us a number in seconds.  In pseudocode:

```
scale = totalSeconds / totalPixels
timeDelta = translation * scale
currentTime = oldTime + timeDelta
```

So I would rewrite your code like this:

```
let totalTime = self.avPlayer.currentItem!.duration
print("time: \(CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime))")
self.avPlayer.pause()

// BEGIN NEW CODE
let touchDelta = swipeGesture.translationInView(self.view).x
let scale = CGFloat(CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime)) / self.view.bounds.width
let timeDelta = touchDelta * scale
let currentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds((avPlayer.currentItem?.currentTime())!) + Float64(timeDelta)
// END NEW CODE

print(currentTime)
if currentTime >= 0 && currentTime <= CMTimeGetSeconds(totalTime) {
    let newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(currentTime, Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    print(newTime)
    self.avPlayer.seekToTime(newTime)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, then i create the UISlider and set the action method is given below,

declare AVPlayer is `var playerVal = AVPlayer()`

```
@IBAction func sliderAction(sender: UISlider) {

    playerVal.pause()
    displayLink.invalidate()
    let newTime:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Double(self.getAudioDuration() as! NSNumber) * Double(sender.value), playerVal.currentTime().timescale)
    playerVal.seekToTime(newTime)

    updateTime()

    playerVal.play()

    deepLink()


 }
```

And another method is,

```
func updateTime() {

        let currentTime = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(playerItem1.currentTime()))
        let minutes = currentTime/60
        let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

        let maxTime =  Float(self.getAudioDuration() as! NSNumber)
        let maxminutes = maxTime / 60
        let maxseconds = maxTime - maxminutes * 60

        startValue.text = NSString(format: "%.2f:%.2f", minutes,seconds) as String
        stopValue.text = NSString(format: "%.2f:%.2f", maxminutes,maxseconds) as String
    }
```

I have used CADisplayLink and declare `var displayLink = CADisplayLink()`, its used continue(automatically) playing audios. code is

```
func deepLink() {
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: ("updateSliderProgress"))
        displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }

func updateSliderProgress(){
        let progress = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(playerVal.currentTime())) / Float(self.getAudioDuration() as! NSNumber)
        sliderView.setValue(Float(progress), animated: false)
    }
```

if you see this above answer, you have get idea, hope its helpful